# Error when deploying stable jenkins charts via kubernetes : curl performs SSL certificate verification by default

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher

I have installed Rancher 2 and created a kubernetes cluster of internal vm's ( no AWS / gcloud).

The cluster is up and running. We are behind Corp proxy.

1) Installed Kubectl and executed kubectl cluster-info . It listed my cluster information correctly.

2) Installed helm

3) Configured helm referencing [Rancher Helm Init](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/ha/helm-init/)

4) Tried installing Jenkins charts via helm

```
 helm install --namespace jenkins --name jenkins -f values.yaml stable/jenkins
```

The values.yaml has proxy details.

```
---
  Master:
    ServiceType: "ClusterIP"
    AdminPassword: "adminpass111"
    Cpu: "200m"
    Memory: "256Mi"
    InitContainerEnv:
      - name: "http_proxy"
        value: "http://proxyuserproxypass@proxyname:8080"
      - name: "https_proxy"
        value: "http://proxyuserproxypass@proxyname:8080"
    ContainerEnv:
      - name: "http_proxy"
        value: "http://proxyuserproxypass@proxyname:8080"
      - name: "https_proxy"
        value: "http://proxyuserproxypass@proxyname:8080"
    JavaOpts: >-
      -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyname
      -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
      -Dhttp.proxyUser=proxyuser
      -Dhttp.proxyPassword=proxypass
      -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyname
      -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
      -Dhttps.proxyPassword=proxypass
      -Dhttps.proxyUser=proxyuser
  Persistence:
    ExistingClaim: "jk-volv-pvc"
    Size: "10Gi"
```

5) The workloads are created. However the Pods are stuck.Logs complains about SSL certificate verification.

How to turn SSL verification off.  I dont see an option to set in values.yaml.
We cannot turn off installing plugins during deployment as well.

Do we need to add SSL cert when deploying charts?

[image]

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues as you had.  In my case it was due to the fact that my DNS domain had a wildcard A record.  So updates.jenkins.io.mydomain.com would resolve fine.  After removing the wildcard, that fails now, so the host will then properly interpret updates.jenkins.io, as updates.jenkins.io.

This is fully documented here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/64924